# Music transfer and playlists

Tags: mp3

Is there an app that will allow you to make playlists with your music (on your computer) and then transfer those playlists, and the associated MP3 files, over to the phone?

I'd prefer not to have to "Sync" stuff because of all the headaches that syncing carries with it, but I just don't see anything in the market that has this functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a further answer I forgot there is [Media Monkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com) which just has basic USB copy which will do what you want - let you make a playlist and just copy it to your phone.

Comment: This looks like a very good answer, but it's missing a vital piece of information - where do you copy the playlist to?

Answer (score 1):

Most apps use M3U playlist which is a pretty standard format.  You can manually sync or sync your playlists using DoubleTwist for `insert OS here`.  I dont even believe that youre required to run doubleTwist on your phone.

Also Cubed has the ability to create and edit playlists right on the phone

Comment: I tried putting an m3u file (test.m3u) on my phone in sdcard/Music/Playlists.  In that file, I put the name of one mp3 file that is found on the sdcard. I was expecting the Music app to find a playlist called test, with a single song in it.  But no such playlist was found.

Is there a special directory where I need to put playlist files?  When I create a playlist within the Music app - where on the system is that playlist stored? I keep losing playlists everytime I flash a ROM.  I'd like to know where to put playlists and how to preserve them through a ROM flash.

Thanks

Comment: It works for me (Android 2.3): Create a text file with one file name per line, stored next to the actual mp3 files. After scanning the SD card again, this shows up under Playlists in the standard Music player app.

Answer (score 1):

Why not install "DropBox" on your PC and on your Phone. You can drag and drop files either way back and forth then ;) I haven't tried it with a playlist. But certainly done it for MP3 and other files.

Comment: I have drop box and it works great for file transfer but I'm specifically looking to manage playlists on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

After years of different problems with iSyncr, I just found out that the "File Manager+" app can give me fpt address to access the mobile from the pc (using WinSCP on PC), if on same wi-fi.

Now I just copy files both sides, and refresh iTunes =)

Also, if using iTunes to organize files on folders, watch out after you refresh, if you rename artists and albums. You'll need to update file structure on mobile as well, if it's your case (it's mine).

Answer (score 0):

I tried Media Monkey. Not the right fit. It is not clear how it handles playlist references, and appears to pull all the music with playlists off the source phone and recreate them on the target phone. (When the music is already on target phone.)  I contacted their support with questions and did not hear back.

Tried dropbox. Not quite right, because the m3u files need to be tweaked by hand. IOW: It is fine for moving media files (and poss also m3u files), but it doesn't give you working playlists on the target phone.

Ultimately, wasn't that hard, but took some dancing. I describe the process [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/244671/155633).