# Move playlist from one application to another in android

Tags: music-player, google-play-music

So I have **Google's Play Music** application that I used till now. But since couple of days I'm facing issues with this app, it hangs a lot, doesn't respond to the commands, and I even updated it few times and currently its updated to the latest version.

Now I have another **inbuilt music app of Asus** and I am wondering if there's a way to **transfer the playlists** that I have in Play Music to the Asus Music player app? I mean, idk, is there some playlist file which if I'll transfer will create the playlists in the Asus Music player app. *(I know it sounds kinda lame, but would be very helpful)*

Also, the playlists that I currently have, has too many songs in it. So creating these playlists altogether from the beginning in the other app (Asus one) wouldn't be a proper solution here.

Thanks!

Comment: Google Play music playlists are saved in a .pla file which can be found in Playlist folder in the internal memory. I don't know if your built-in music app can read it.

Comment: @esQmo okay,  will look into it. fyi, the inbuilt app is the music player app of Asus.

Comment: I've found this post which seems to contradict what I said: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15045/where-and-how-does-android-store-music-playlists

Comment: Besides, some apps can do the job also. Try Playlist Backup from Google Play

Comment: Your best bet is if your new music app has an "import playlists" option. Google's Play music is no more, but if you have good music apps they should have options like somewhere in settings to both export and import playlists.