# How to migrate playlists (for local music library)

Tags: applications, music, android-11

My old and new Android phones have SD cards, and the entire music library (mp3 & flac) is on the SD card.

On the new phone, the playlists are all there, but they have no songs in them.

I use BlackPlayer EX on old and new phones.

Old phone: Android 10 with SD card
New phone: Android 11 with SD card

(Both phones are Sony Xperia models, fwiw)

How to get the playlists to migrate properly?

Comment: @beeshyams Your comment about scoped storage appears not to apply. On the new phone, the music player sees and plays all the music just fine. AND it is able to read all the playlist names from the db where that is stored. (The db must have been migrated by one of the migration processes.)

Comment: Good, at least scoped storage isn't the problem. Not sure what can be done

Comment: You can try [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devfinition.playsync) or some others on Play Store

Comment: @beeshyams That app seems to be for streaming services. My library is local. I don't see mention of support for local music libraries?

Comment: @beeshyams I solved it. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  Black Player on both old and new phone, local MP3 and FLAC files on SD card (in /music/ folder on old and new phone). Old android phone on android 9/10  New android phone on android 10/11/12.

Steps:

(Assumes Windows laptop, adjust as appro for Mac)

1. On old phone, in Black Player, export all playlists to m3u
2. On new phone, in Black Player, delete all empty playlists (if they migrated), and create one new test playlist of two or three tracks
3. Install the WebDAV Server app (the free one by "The Olive Tree") on both old and new phone
4. Start WebDAV server on old phone, give permissions, ignore warning that is made for older version of Android
5. On laptop, in Explorer, right click on My Computer, choose Map Drive, and enter the full url to the webdav (http://:8080 -- this is shown in the WebDAV app)
6. The newly mapped drive, say Z:, open in Explorer, scroll all the way down, you should see your playlists as m3u files
7. Copy all of them to local laptop (Say to c:\temp\oldphone)
8. Now do steps 3 and 4 on NEW phone, and then copy over the test playlist
9. Using VSCode or Notepad++, open the test playlist from the new phone, note the path to the files
10. Now do a global replace on the playlists to adjust the path to the mp3/flac files in all the m3u files
11. Now copy all the m3u files to the NEW phone
12. Now in Black Player, at the bottom of the Playlists area, select Import Playlist
13. Select ALL the playlists, and select Import

TADA!